# jQuery UI toggle for scale effect not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my site, (I can't share URL here, you'd need to login to see there), I'm using my required jQuery UI animation properly. But when I tested the same code again in localhost, it just doesn't work:

I have added the fiddle:

If you try the fiddle, it works perfectly, but when I run the exactly same code, I see following **behavior**:

Page is loaded:

1. Click on button, the bell resizes to 0 and hides.
2. Click again, instead of resizing back to 100% with animation, it quickly resizes to 100% ( without animantion), then again resizes to 0% (with animantion) instead of 100%. Just after the animation, it again resizes to 100%. So, it is finally shown, but there's some wrong / repeatetion that I don't understand.

Here's the approx. 'timeline' of 2nd point to get an idea:

**Time  - action**

0% - Click

0.1% - Image resizes to 100% from 0% (no animation);

0.2% (say) - Image resizes to 0% from 100% (with animation);

99.1% (say) - Image resizes to 100% from 0% (no animation);

100% - done

This repeats when you keep clicking.

**Correct** behaviour (as happening in fiddle):

1. Click on button, the bell resizes to 0 and hides with animantion.
2. Click again, the bell resizes to 100% and is shown again with animation.

**PS:**

When I wrote individual jQuery (`.show('scale', 2000)` and `.hide('scale', 2000)`), things were working everywhere.

EDIT 1:

When I further tested with other effects like `clip`, `drop` it didn't cause any issue. So I think problem is with `scale` effect

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click", "button", function(){
    $("#nbutton .b1").toggle("scale", 2000);
   });
});
```

```css
  #nbutton{
            height: 60px;
            width: 60px;
            border-radius: 50px;
            position: fixed;
            right: 40px;
            bottom: 30px;
            border: none;
            color: white;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
            cursor: pointer;
            z-index: 100;
        }
        .nbutton{
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            position: absolute;
        }
        .b1{
            z-index: 2;
            background-image: url('https://test.roadcast.co.in/app/assets/img/bell.png');
            background-size: contain;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
        .b2{
            z-index: 1;
            background-image: url('https://test.roadcast.co.in/app/assets/img/bellcross.png');
            background-size: contain;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            transition: transform 0.400s ease;
            transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="nbutton">
    <div style="position: relative">
        <div class="nbutton b1">
        </div>
        <div class="nbutton b2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: What browser are you using and have you tried any other browsers? In Chrome Win 10 it looks great but then again, I don't know what it looks like w/o jQueryUI. A percentage of 0.1% is hardly discernible...

Comment: 0.1% means just after click. I just assumed it so you can understand the meaning of 'just after click'. Further jQuery UI is compulsory. Same behavior in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use JQuery `animate()` with `step` or multiple `animate()` like as follow.there you need to calculate you `ease` respect for `duration`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click", "button", function(){
        if($("#nbutton .b1").css('display') =='block')
        {
          var div = $("#nbutton .b1");

          div.animate({height: '60px',width: '60px'}, 200);
          div.animate({height: '0px',width: '0px',margin:'50%'}, 200);
          div.animate({height: '60px',width: '60px',margin:'0%'}, 1600);        
          div.animate({height: '0px',width: '0px',margin:'50%'}, 200);
          div.animate({height: '60px',width: '60px',margin:'0%'},200);
          $("#nbutton .b1").css('display','none'); 
        }
        else
        {
          $("#nbutton .b1").css('display','block');
          div.animate({height: '0px',width: '0px',margin:'50%'}, 1000);

        }
       }); 
});
```

Comment: This didn't answer my question.

Comment: you check the animation in the fiddle or not.